# Can't open office documents from SharePoint site

Tags: 2013, excel, word, office

I'm using SharePoint 2013 and some users, I'll repeat, only SOME of them can't open office files in their client application (word, excel...). I don't know what is the problem because I can open documents from my machine but when I log in to another machine (colleague that can't open documents) I'm also unable to open documents. So, problem is in machine. I tried:

- removing office cache files
- Adding SharePoint site to Trusted zone
- Repairing office installation...

Nothing helps. Message after a longer period of "downloading": Sorry, we couldn't find . It is possible it was moved, renamed or deleted? Sometimes there is an another message...

Comment: I have this same problem with Word 2013: can't open documents from SP, but when I try open this same document in Word 2007 it's working perfect.
And I don't know why...

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved by installing newest updates (`from 5. December 2015. to 15. December 2015.`). I'm not sure but probably this update solved problem:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3023068

Answer (score 0):

1. On the Internet Explorer > Tools > Internet Options > Advanced tab > click Restore defaults button > Click "OK"
2. On the Internet Explorer > Tools > Internet Options > Connection tab > click "LAN Settings" > de-select "Automatically Detect Settings"